# Trouble listing printers with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, printing

So here's the original problem:

I have an Excel file with a button that runs a macro. This macro needs to print the sheet to 2 separate network printers. The workbook will be run on multiple different computers on the network.

My current code looks like so:

```
Application.ActivePrinter = "Printer-A on Ne02:"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Application.ActivePrinter = "Printer-B on Ne05:"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

The problem lies with the `on Ne02:` and `on Ne05:`. These values differ from one computer to another. E.g.:

- Printer-A on Ne03:
- Printer-B on Ne02:
- Printer-A on Ne07:
- etc

I can circumvent the issue by displaying the "select a printer" dialog and forcing users to choose the printer manually, but I would prefer for this to be automatic.

I have tried using the Windows Script Host Object Model to list all of the printers like so:

```
Function FindPrinter(name As String)
    Dim nwo As New WshNetwork
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fullName As String

    For i = 0 To (nwo.EnumPrinterConnections.Count / 2) - 1
        If InStr(nwo.EnumPrinterConnections(i * 2 + 1), name) > 0 Then
            fullName = nwo.EnumPrinterConnections(i * 2 + 1)
        End If
    Next i

    ' Returns the LAST printer that matches
    FindPrinter = fullName
End Function

Sub MyMacro()
    ActivePrinter = FindPrinter("Printer-A")
End Sub
```

However this fails. If I look at the output of `FindPrinter`, it's only returning the string "Printer-A" without the "on Ne02:"

How can I get a full list of printers installed, including this "on NeXX:" bit? Or, alternatively, how can I set a printer as active knowing only its name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the Test sub at the bottom:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER As Long = &H80000001
Private Const HKCU = HKEY_CURRENT_USER
Private Const KEY_QUERY_VALUE = &H1&
Private Const ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259&
Private Const ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234

Private Declare Function RegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32" _
    Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" ( _
    ByVal HKey As Long, _
    ByVal lpSubKey As String, _
    ByVal ulOptions As Long, _
    ByVal samDesired As Long, _
    phkResult As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function RegEnumValue Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    Alias "RegEnumValueA" ( _
    ByVal HKey As Long, _
    ByVal dwIndex As Long, _
    ByVal lpValueName As String, _
    lpcbValueName As Long, _
    ByVal lpReserved As Long, _
    lpType As Long, _
    lpData As Byte, _
    lpcbData As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function RegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal HKey As Long) As Long

Public Function GetPrinterFullNames() As String()
Dim Printers() As String ' array of names to be returned
Dim PNdx As Long    ' index into Printers()
Dim HKey As Long    ' registry key handle
Dim Res As Long     ' result of API calls
Dim Ndx As Long     ' index for RegEnumValue
Dim ValueName As String ' name of each value in the printer key
Dim ValueNameLen As Long    ' length of ValueName
Dim DataType As Long        ' registry value data type
Dim ValueValue() As Byte    ' byte array of registry value value
Dim ValueValueS As String   ' ValueValue converted to String
Dim CommaPos As Long        ' position of comma character in ValueValue
Dim ColonPos As Long        ' position of colon character in ValueValue
Dim M As Long               ' string index

' registry key in HCKU listing printers
Const PRINTER_KEY = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices"

PNdx = 0
Ndx = 0
' assume printer name is less than 256 characters
ValueName = String$(256, Chr(0))
ValueNameLen = 255
' assume the port name is less than 1000 characters
ReDim ValueValue(0 To 999)
' assume there are less than 1000 printers installed
ReDim Printers(1 To 1000)

' open the key whose values enumerate installed printers
Res = RegOpenKeyEx(HKCU, PRINTER_KEY, 0&, _
    KEY_QUERY_VALUE, HKey)
' start enumeration loop of printers
Res = RegEnumValue(HKey, Ndx, ValueName, _
    ValueNameLen, 0&, DataType, ValueValue(0), 1000)
' loop until all values have been enumerated
Do Until Res = ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS
    M = InStr(1, ValueName, Chr(0))
    If M > 1 Then
        ' clean up the ValueName
        ValueName = Left(ValueName, M - 1)
    End If
    ' find position of a comma and colon in the port name
    CommaPos = InStr(1, ValueValue, ",")
    ColonPos = InStr(1, ValueValue, ":")
    ' ValueValue byte array to ValueValueS string
    On Error Resume Next
    ValueValueS = Mid(ValueValue, CommaPos + 1, ColonPos - CommaPos)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' next slot in Printers
    PNdx = PNdx + 1
    Printers(PNdx) = ValueName & " on " & ValueValueS
    ' reset some variables
    ValueName = String(255, Chr(0))
    ValueNameLen = 255
    ReDim ValueValue(0 To 999)
    ValueValueS = vbNullString
    ' tell RegEnumValue to get the next registry value
    Ndx = Ndx + 1
    ' get the next printer
    Res = RegEnumValue(HKey, Ndx, ValueName, ValueNameLen, _
        0&, DataType, ValueValue(0), 1000)
    ' test for error
    If (Res <> 0) And (Res <> ERROR_MORE_DATA) Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
' shrink Printers down to used size
ReDim Preserve Printers(1 To PNdx)
Res = RegCloseKey(HKey)
' Return the result array
GetPrinterFullNames = Printers
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim Printers() As String
    Dim N As Long
    Dim S As String
    Printers = GetPrinterFullNames()
    For N = LBound(Printers) To UBound(Printers)
        S = S & Printers(N) & vbNewLine
    Next N
    MsgBox S, vbOKOnly, "Printers"
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! Although I'm not 100% sure how. Whenever I tried copying code with the `Private Declare` syntax before I got a string of errors. I'll try this out on a few other computers and make sure I can get the printers working everywhere.

Comment: This is using the registry in Windows. I am pretty sure it will only work on a windows based OS although, I would like to hear otherwise.

Comment: It worked on every computer in my house, however when I sent it to the client to try on the actual computers it failed giving an error when trying to call method `Application.ActivePrinter` (e.g. - the printer name was invalid). Since it worked for me I'm still marking this as correct, as I feel any issues he is having now are either configuration problems or user error.

Comment: @stevendesu I am guessing that your client does not have the name of the printer set correctly (I don't know how you are getting the name in the first place).  You could always modify the code above to make a list of printers from your client so that you can adjust the name accordingly. Otherwise, you could come up with a way that they can run one script (or an error handler) to set the printer names that the client want to use, and after selected, only those printers will be used in your script. Also, check what OS they are running on. We many need a different solution for full cross platform

Answer (score 0):

The connection is the first part of the enumeration. Essentially `.Item(i + 1) & " on ' & .Item(i)`. In your code this would be,

```
fullName = nwo.EnumPrinterConnections(i * 2 + 1) & " on " & nwo.EnumPrinterConnections(i * 2)
```

You will have to fill a list of the similar printers; currently, you are only returning the last match.

Comment: This did not work. It returned "Printer-A on 192.168.0.6"

Comment: That would seem to solve your problem as Ne02 or Ne07 might change from machine to machine but the network printer's LAN IP address is not going to change. I always used to set my network printer's IPs by MAC so DHCP didn't throw them a new one.

Comment: Trying to use "Printer-A on 192.168.0.6" in `ActivePrinter = ...` throws an error for me