# Choosing a default printer from a list instead of hard coding it in

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I currently have a macro for batch printing.  It works perfectly; however, the printing option is hard coded in by setting a default printer with the following code.

`CreateObject("WScript.Network").SetDefaultPrinter "\\vs-dc.CCC.internal\RICOH MPC3503 - Office 2nd Flr WKRM"`

Does anyone know of a way to open a dialog box with all the printer options on the network so anyone could use this?  It doesn't have to set the default back to the original but if it did that would be an absolute plus.

My thought process was to somehow have the form set the printer you choose to  `Selected printer = ChosenPrinter` and then use that.

`CreateObject("WScript.Network").SetDefaultPrinter ChosenPrinter`

I've also seen how you can set it back to the original default using the:

`ActivePrinter = OrigPrinter` and once it's done you set it back to that.

If anyone knows how to incorporate all this in with each other that would be amazing. I'll include the full code below in case that is necessary.

```
Sub GetFiles(StartFolder As String, Pattern As String, _
         DoSubfolders As Boolean, ByRef colFiles As Collection)

Dim f As String, sf As String, subF As New Collection, s

If Right(StartFolder, 1) <> "\" Then StartFolder = StartFolder & "\"

f = Dir(StartFolder & Pattern)
Do While Len(f) > 0
    colFiles.Add StartFolder & f
    f = Dir()
Loop

sf = Dir(StartFolder, vbDirectory)
Do While Len(sf) > 0
    If sf <> "." And sf <> ".." Then
        If (GetAttr(StartFolder & sf) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                subF.Add StartFolder & sf
        End If
    End If
    sf = Dir()
Loop

For Each s In subF
    GetFiles CStr(s), Pattern, True, colFiles
Next s

End Sub
```

.

```
Sub BatchPrint()

Dim colFiles As New Collection
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long

Set colFiles = New Collection

CreateObject("WScript.Network").SetDefaultPrinter "\\vs-dc.CCC.internal\RICOH MPC3503 - Office 2nd Flr WKRM"

LastRow = Sheet1.Range("B9999").End(xlUp).Row
Dim countFiles As Integer 'Storing the number of files found
With Sheet1

For CustRow = 3 To LastRow
countFiles = colFiles.Count
GetFiles "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\", Sheet1.Range("B" & CustRow) & ".pdf", True, colFiles
If countFiles = colFiles.Count Then
Sheet1.Range("B" & CustRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next CustRow

End With

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To colFiles.Count
Debug.Print colFiles(i)

PrintFile (colFiles(i))

Next i

Set colFiles = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575572/trouble-listing-printers-with-excel-vba

Comment: `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show` might work for you

Comment: I tried using the solution above but since I have a collection it would show up for every item being printed in the collection.  If there was a way to only have to press it once then it would work for me but I couldn't figure that out

Comment: Which solution? Sounds like the solution proposed by @TimWilliams would work for you since the `xlDialogPrinterSetup` dialog will set the active printer, so you can let the user select the active printer once at the beginning if you'd like.

Comment: The xlDialogPrinterSetup lets me choose a printer; however, the collection still prints to the 'default' not the 'active' printer.  At least that's what I'm having happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were printing from Excel, you could simply use

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
```

to let the user select the active printer (for Excel) at the beginning of the macro (as suggested by Tim Williams).

As you noted, this won't change the Default Printer for Windows as the Active Printer is just a local setting for the Excel Application.

Since you mentioned that the Default Printer is used by the procedure/function `PrintFile` in your code, you can then set the Default Printer right after setting the ActivePrinter using:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Network").SetDefaultPrinter Left(ActivePrinter, Len(ActivePrinter) - 9)
```

Note that we need to remove the last 9 characters from the ActivePrinter string since ActivePrinter includes information about the printer port number which looks like this " on Ne##:".

Comment: I actually just tried this and when I have it in the that order it throws an error for the line ```CreateObject("WScript.Network").SetDefaultPrinter ActivePrinter```, I can't figure out why this isn't working

Comment: @JoshL – You're right there is a small adjustment you need to make this work. I've edited my answer to reflect this.